# Set TraceId from String Attribute Value in Open Telemetry // Cast String to Byte Array

Tags: go, open-telemetry

we are trying to set a TraceID with a the OpenTelemetry Transform Processor [1].

There is a way to set the TraceID with a hard coded value [2] like this (the example shows a SpanID, but TraceID works too).

```
traces:
    set(span_id, SpanID(0x0000000000000000))
```

We want to set it to a value we have stored in an attribute. We tried

```
traces:
    set(trace_id, attributes["traceID"])
```

where `attributes["traceID"]` is a String `0x00000000000000000000000000000000`.

This won't work, but if we try

```
traces:
    set(trace_id,TraceID(attributes["traceID"]))
```

the collector won't even start, since we are trying to give a String, where a Byte Slice is expected

```
collector server run finished with error: invalid configuration: processor "transform" has invalid configuration: invalid argument at position 1 invalid argument for slice parameter at position 0, must be a byte slice literal
```

We tried different approaches to cast the String to a Byte Array but none did work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance, kind regards!

[1] https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/fbb8ff9658b3bac7892dea6c7d49f40afe154bd8/processor/transformprocessor

[2] https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/pkg/ottl#update-a-spans-id

Answer (score 1):

We found the answer:

```
- set(trace_id.string,attributes["traceID"])
```

Works just fine :)